# How is managed the iteration here?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iteration

Suppose I have a class that return a `List<string>` :

```
public List<string> ListaProvince
{
    get
    {
        return ListaDelleProvince.ToList();
    }
}
```

and this method is called many times from many Class. How can I get sure that, if a class is iterating the 10° element in the list, the next Class start to iterate it from the beginning?

I guess the instance get the same reference... so the same iterator.

Comment: _the same reference... so the same iterator._  - __No.__ Each `foreach` / `ToList()` gets its own iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess the instance get the same reference... so the same iterator.

Even if `ToList` happens to be such that it returns the same instance of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`<sup>*</sup> , you would get a different instance of `IEnumerator<T>` in `GetEnumerator()`, so you are safe.

---

<sup>*</sup>  If your `ListaDelleProvince` is a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, you would get different instances from the calls of `ToList()`.

Comment: Even using `ToDictionary()`?

Comment: @markzzz Yes, LINQ's `ToDictionary()` gives you a new instance as well.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is impossible to answer without knowing what `ListaDelleProvince` is, but if we assume it is a fairly standard implementation, it will be returning a separate and independent list each and every time `ListaProvince` is accessed - copying the list. Iterators on different lists are *certainly* independent.

However, even if the *same* list was returned: iterators (via `GetEnumerator()`) are *usually* independent of each-other (i.e. it would be a non-standard implementation if this were the case, but it does happen sometimes).

Comment: `ListaDelleProvince` is a List<string>. Why it will return separate list each time? It points to the same object...

Comment: @markzzz because that is what `Enumerable.ToList` *does*; it does **not** return the same list

Comment: Sorry Marc lost you on the last line, what non-standard implementation did you mean ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta say I wrote a custom iterator block over something like an `IDataReader` or a `NetworkStream` - those are forwards-only non-buffered non-repeatable inputs; separate enumerators **cannot** be isolated. Iterators on things like lists and arrays, however, are normally isolated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method will cause your property to return a new copy of the `ListaDelleProvince` sequence each time it is read, so all subsequent uses would be safe.

That said, assuming you're using the retrieved list just for reading, even this step isn't required (and will unnecessarily hurt performance). Each `foreach` loop will cause a new enumerator to be instantiated for reading the list, so you can have as many of these iterating over the same list as you like (provided they don't modify it).

```
public List<string> ListaProvince
{
    get
    {
        return ListaDelleProvince;
    }
}
```